Tailwind's 'select-none' class not working on mobile safari
I have this block of code in my NextJS app:
    <div className="select-none">
        bro
    </div>

but somehow I can still select it in mobile safari. I tried putting the same className even on the parents.
It does work on mobile Firefox though, so it's probably a safari thing. I can't find anything about this on google.

So it is indeed a safari thing. user-select, which is what tailwind uses, doesn't work on safari. You have to use -webkit-user-select. By default, tailwind in NextJS does not prefix properties.
Solution:
You have to install autoprefixer
npm install -D autoprefixer

then add it to postcss.config.mjs

source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/browser-support
